# Change fan & light control into 2 separate switches

Tags: electrical, switch, fans

Hello all this is my first post and hope I cover everything needed to answer this question. I have a switch that controls a cieling fan/light in the living room of my house that was built in 2001. 
The other switch in the same gang controls an outlet on another wall.  This outlet is also controled by another switch on a different wall.

Confused? Here I will provide pictures to help in case I suck at explaining...

[image]

So above is an outline of what switches control what...

The switch that is circled (controls the fan) is the one to focus on.  This switch has the control above from home depot and controls the fan and lights in the fan, they both have dimmer/different fan settings.  The other switch controls that outlet beneath it on the picture.  As you can see there is another switch on a different wall that controls that outlet as well.  FYI the switch that is next to the fan control (which is cirlced) seems to be the secondary switch meaning it will turn the outlet on and off but if the other switch is flicked off, whatever is plugged into that outlet turns off no matter what the circled switch is on.

My goal, is to eliminate the switch that controls the outlet (want to keep it live, meaning anything i plug into the switch will work) but remove that switch pictured in the circle.  Instead I would like to separate the fan/light switch into 2.  This should work since the gang box is already meant for 2 switches.  I am going to use the GE Z-Wave fan control and the GE Z-Wave dimmer switch to accomplish this.

Below is what the gang box looks like once removed from the wall.

[image]

Ok so to inform you about this pic, the left romex is I think is controlling the fan/light. The red wire is connected to the yellow wire coming from the fan/light combo switch.  The black wire coming from romex is connected to the red wire coming from the fan/light switch. The silver or white (which i marked as B/N and you can ignor the N part) is connected to the black wire coming from the fan/light switch (I think this is hot wire from testing, which I think is strange considering I thought all hot wires were black!)  and the Green wire is attached to the Green wire from the fan/light switch.  Now the blue circles are wire nuts where multiple wires are attached... The middle romex connects to a couple of things (the black is connect to the switch and black nut, which is hot when i test is!!! ) ....it seems and the romex on the right hand side seems to control the switch which controls the outlet (and we are trying to eliminate but things still work if they are plugged in)

Again the main goal is to remove the switch to the outlet and replace the switch for fan and light to 2 different controls!

Thank you for all your help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Are the other two white wires in the box (from the left and right NM cables) *really* connected to the grounds?

Comment: Also, is the black wire from the right hand NM cable connected through to the black or red wire going to the middle NM cable?

Comment: yes the white wires from the left and right are wire nutted to the copper wires... copper wires from all 3 are all wire nutted together then 1 comes out and meets the 2 white wire from left and right hand side together.

Comment: as for the black wire on the right hand side... it is connect to the copper screw in the switch... the red is connected to that switch as well and the black wire from the middle is connected to that switch as well and is hot when i test it... that switch i am referring to is the switch beside the fan/light control. this is the switch i am trying to eliminate